# How does float variable store negative values which are not in their range?

Tags: c++, floating-point, range

The range of `float` values is 3.4e-38 to 3.4e+38. So the float variables should not store negative values. But float variables are storing negative values. Please explain it to me.

```
#include<iostream.h>
void main()
{ float ab=-3.456;
cout<<ab; }
```

Output:

```
-3.456
```

Comment: Floating point numbers have a sign. Read http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: there's currently no common positive-only floating-point format in use

Answer (score 2):

The range for single precision float is 2<sup>−126</sup> ≈ 1.18 × 10<sup>−38</sup> to (2−2<sup>−23</sup>) × 2<sup>127</sup> ≈ 3.4 × 10<sup>38</sup> for positive values and similar but reverse for negative values: -3.4 × 10<sup>38</sup> to -1.18 × 10<sup>−38</sup> because IEEE-754 uses sign-magnitude format where sign bit is store separately

Read more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)

Answer (score 1):

These are largest and smallest **positive** values.

> In the internal representation, there is 1 bit for the sign (S), 8
>   bits for the exponent (E), and 23 bits for the fraction (F). The bits
>   are mapped with the fraction in bit 0 to bit 22, the exponent in bit
>   23 to bit 30, and the sign in bit 31.

[More](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/macxhelp/v6v81/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.vacpp6m.doc%2Fproguide%2Fref%2Frvimaebf.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Basically float consists of three numbers

```
significant * base ^ exponent
```

Significant part and exponent part both can have their separate sign. 
So actually float range is:

```
float   32 bits -3.4E+38 to +3.4E+38    about 7 decimal digits
```

[Floating point on wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point)

[IEEE standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)